# PHP; Error reporting from inside a function

Tags: php, error-handling

So if a function produces a warning/notice we get the LINE within the function.

I could validate before, during AND/OR after the function call but I am curious is there a way to AUTOMATICALLY be given the error producing **LINE_** of the function call that called the function?

Comment: No, I don't think PHP automatically produces tracebacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a try catch statement like this:

```
try{
    //your code that errors here
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Line number:" . $e->getLine();
    //you could throw the exception here again
    //throw $e;
    //or create a new exception and throw that with the data you supply
    //$newException = new Exception('New message goes here', 'exception code goes here');
    //then throw it
    //throw $newException;
    exit;
}
```

Here is the link to the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getline.php

You might also be interested in these methods (amongst others) that also belong to the Exception class:

- getMessage
- getCode
- getFile
- getMessage

As per your comment and creating a new exception check out the Exception class here:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Comment: Thx, seems to be the best option going! Much appreciated!

Comment: You can always re-throw the exception within the catch statement. I'll update the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use a PHP IDE with a debugger and set breakpoints, watch the call stack.

Comment: Could be a solution for another fine, not in my case as I cannot sit through the 1000000;s of combinations my code could create, with error reporting I can get an email sent to me.

Comment: You didnt specify whether this was for production code or development